# How can I fix this react-native iOS error?

Tags: react-native

```
error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native` from file `/Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/index.js`, the package `/Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/node_modules/react-native/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * `/Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
  * `/Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:103:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:272:4579)
    at dependencies.map.relativePath (/Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:376:19)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:374:16)
    at /Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:212:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:313)
    at /Users/ios/Desktop/android/android/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:473
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: are you using cocoapods or something like that? its seem like the packager dont find the react-native core libs. try to start a new project. or do npm install in your main project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade your react-native recently?  If yes, then that might be the issue.

If not, check your `node_modules` folder for the file.

If nothing works, Then try this:
Delete the `node_modules` folder and close the packager. 
Then reinstall using the command `npm install` from your project directory.